# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'namelist'

Tags: python

I am trying to create a very simple log parser script in python. Everything is going as planned except the script on the target machine is returning this error (the script works on a unix machine though quite fine):

```
for name in root.namelist():
Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'namelist'
```

Python versions appear to be the same (2.7.3 on both machines). Any ideas?

Script itself:

```
import zipfile
import os
import re

string1 = "searchstring" # raw_input("usrinput: ")

try:
   root = zipfile.ZipFile("/home/testuser/docs/testzip.zip", "r")
except:
   root = "testfolder/"
for name in root.namelist():
    if name.find(".") > 0:
        f = root.open(name)
        searchlines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            regex1 = "(.*)" + re.escape(string1) + "(.*)"
            if re.match (regex1, line):
                for l in searchlines[i-4:i+4]: print l,
                print
```

Comment: It means the `except` block was executed and `root` is now a string `"testfolder/"`.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use blanket `except` statements; you don't know what was wrong with your `zipfile.ZipFile()` call now.

Comment: hardcoding paths is never a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `root = "testfolder/"` it doesn't have any namelist as its attribute.

Type of root is string

Which in turn looking at your code means, `root = zipfile.ZipFile("/home/testuser/docs/testzip.zip", "r")` generated an exception

in exception block try to use `except Exception, ex:` and then print `ex.message` to understand the type of exception being generated

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I removed the whole Except, since I found out it is not necessary in this case. Real culprit was copying path to the zipfile from total commander on the windows machine. It somehow capitalized the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, `namelist()` is only available for a `zipfile`, not for a `string`.

This happens when the zip file cannot be opened. Check the path where the zip file is located.

Try this and see the output:

```
try:
   root = zipfile.ZipFile("/home/testuser/docs/testzip.zip", "r")
except Exception, msg:
   print msg
   root = "testfolder/"
```

When I tried with a valid zip file, the program worked fine.